# Passing variable from PHP onto Javascript with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to pass a string from PHP onto a javascript file using the `$.getJSON` function but it keeps alerting 'getJSON request failed'. So far, I've tried using the `$.ajax` with and without `async: true` and the regular `$.get` jQuery functions but I get the same problem. I've also tried including the 
`$( document ).ready()` function.

The enterComment function is executed upon sending a form in the php file 'pannkakor.php'. Just to be clear, the `enterComment` function does execute when clicking the button but the `$.getJSON` function fails.

Also worth noting is that I am using the knockout.js framework.

What am I doing wrong?

PHP CODE SNIPPET:

```
<?php
    $username = "test";
    $array = array('username' => $username);
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
this.enterComment = function (comment) {
        $.getJSON("localhost:8888/Sem4/recept/pannkakor.php", function (jsonData) {
            alert("TESTING THAT IT WORKS");
        })
                .done(function () {
                    alert('getJSON request succeeded!');
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('getJSON request failed');
                });
    };
```

HTML/PHP FOR THE FORM SUBMITTED:

```
<form data-bind="submit: enterComment.bind($data,$data.comment )">
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.comment"/>
                            <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: You might try setting the header to JSON before echoing the JSON chunk. `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers developer tools to see if the request is sent correctly and to see what it actually returns. What happens if you surf to the `pannkakor.php` file directly in your browser? You should also check why it fails in your `.fail()` promise. [Read the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) (in the bottom) about how you can get the real error message.

Comment: It seems like my URL was incorrect and I got a network error which I fixed thanks to Magnus Eriksson. Now I'm getting a new error.  "Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 4 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: If the output looks OK when you browse to the page directly (no errors), you might have some white space after your `?>`. This is the reason why it's recommended not to have any closing `?>` on PHP-only files. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Ah, so the problem was that I was not using a PHP-only file, it had HTML in it so the entire HTML was echoed I guess. I solved the problem by creating a new PHP-only file and inserted the PHP code snippet and made the action attribute in the HTML form direct you to the newly created PHP file. I would mark your answer as the best, but it does not seem to be possible with comments